# How to check camera and location permissions with two separate buttons respectively?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

***SOLVED!: Read my own reply below. Somehow it's bugged, I VE TRIED EXACT SAME CODE BEFORE BUT DIDN'T WORK! Now I tried it again, it works. I removed the app several times aswell, nothing about permissions. Weird. So when I use the app.js example below my answer it works. Just scroll down you'll see it. I let this stay here so people can learn from this.***

This is a continuation of my other post here: [How to prompt camera permission when a button is clicked in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261017/how-to-prompt-camera-permission-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-react)
One button checks for location perm and the other is for camera. It works when I do only one, but if I add one more like this, it borks. I tried various ways, nothing works. But I believe I am so close. What am I missing? Docs doesn't show anything complex like this. Here is my app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Button} from 'react-native'
import {Permission, PERMISSION_TYPE} from 'D:/reactbastan/yenibasla/src/AppPermission'

export default class App extends Component {
    checkPermission = () => {
        Permission.checkPermission(PERMISSION_TYPE.location);
    }
    checkPermissiontwo = () =>{
      Permission.checkPermisssion(PERMISSION_TYPE.camera);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>Lokasyon</Text>
                <Button title="Location perm" onPress={this.checkPermission}/>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>Kamera</Text>
                <Button title="Camera perm" onPress={this.checkPermissiontwo}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }})
```

And here is my apppermission.js:

```
import {check, request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';
import {Platform} from 'react-native'

const PLATFORM_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS= { 
    ios:PERMISSIONS.IOS.MICROPHONE,
    android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA
}

const PLATFORM_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS = { 
    //ios için bir şeyler uydur.
    ios:PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA,
   android:PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
   }
   

const REQUEST_PERMISSION_TYPE = {
    camera: PLATFORM_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS,
    location: PLATFORM_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS  
}

const PERMISSION_TYPE= {
    camera: 'camera',
    location: 'location'
}

class AppPermission {

    checkPermission= async (type): Promise<boolean> => {
        console.log("AppPermission checkPermission type:", type)
        const permissions = REQUEST_PERMISSION_TYPE[type][Platform.OS]
        console.log("AppPermission checkPermission permissions:", permissions)
        if(!permissions){
            return true
        }
        try {
        const result = await check(permissions)
        console.log("AppPermission checkPermission result:", result)
        if (result === RESULTS.GRANTED) return true
        return this.requestPermission(permissions)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("AppPermission checkPermission error:", error)
            return false
        }
    }

    requestPermission=async(permissions): Promise<boolean> => {
        console.log("AppPermission requestPermission permissions:", permissions)

try {
    const result = await request(permissions)
    console.log("AppPermission requestPermission result:", result)
    return result === RESULTS.GRANTED
}catch(error) {
    console.log("AppPermission requestPermission error:", error)

    return false
}

    }
}
const Permission = new AppPermission()
export {Permission, PERMISSION_TYPE}
```

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED!: Somehow it's bugged, I VE TRIED EXACT SAME CODE BEFORE BUT DIDN'T WORK! Now I tried it again, it works. I removed the app several times aswell, nothing about permissions. Weird. So when I use this app.js it works fine:***

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Button} from 'react-native'
import {Permission, PERMISSION_TYPE} from 'D:/reactbastan/yenibasla/src/AppPermission'

export default class App extends Component {
    checkLocation = () => {
        Permission.checkPermission(PERMISSION_TYPE.location);
    }
    checkCamera = () => {
      Permission.checkPermission(PERMISSION_TYPE.camera);
    }
  
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>Lokasyon</Text>
                <Button title="Lokasyonu çalıştır" onPress={this.checkLocation}/>

                <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>Kamera</Text>
                <Button title="Kamerayı çalıştır" onPress={this.checkCamera}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }})
```